# How to fixed Error Message resource type in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cultureinfo, resx, uiculture

There is multi lingual application in that we are facing issue with Error Message Resource type.

> Error message data annotation not working as per the current culture.

We have ENGLISH and Spanish Culture files.

**MODEL:**

```
public class MyModel
{
 [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MyLang.Resource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "emailrequired")]
        [Display(Name = "Email", ResourceType = typeof(MyLang.Resource))]
        public string Email { get; set; }

}
```

[image]

When I changed culture using code level then all the title changing correctly but the Error Message not converting to right language.

**CODE:**

```
string cultureName="en"; // or es
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(cultureName);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

**View**

```
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-md-2">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "form-control-label" })                                        
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add your view code ?

Comment: @gobes added view code. use Labels & Text

Comment: It seems the english message is the default one - as if you hadn't defined another. I don't remember how the framework is behaving when it doesn't find a resource; are those resources where you expect them to be ? BTW, your model field is `Email`, but your error message ask for a company name.

Comment: Here i have given fields and use same TextBox For and ValidateMessageFor. for an example of Email. same company Name.. validation message coming issue. and idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the jquery validation script in the view.

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```